# Macbook Pro Retina Won't boot after OS X 10.11.4 Update

Tags: macos, mac, boot, ssd, osx-el-capitan

This computer is a Late 2013 Macbook Pro Retina: 256GB *SSD* (not hdd, important). This computer is treated with insanely good care, and is not damaged physically whatsoever.

So yesterday night, I installed 10.11.4, which was already downloaded, and I really wanted to get rid of the "1" notification thing, so I chose to update it.

The problem starts when today morning, my mac would not boot. AT ALL. And when I mean at all, I really do mean at all. I was getting no signs of life whatsoever. Completely dead.
I then held the power button for around 10 seconds and finally got something to happen, only to find out it was showing the "folder with question mark" icon. Sad.
I have tried Recovery, failed, Safe mode, failed, Verbose mode, failed, I tried Internet Recovery, and the first time I tried it, it game an error message of something like -3400F (not exactly sure, as I didnt memorize it).

The second time I tried it though, it DID boot into Internet Recovery, but I couldn't do much. I went into disk utility, only to find out, Macintosh HD, was not mounted, and could not be mounted, SMART status wouldnt work, and it didnt give any info on partitions, space, size, blah blah blah. I tried verifying the disk, Got an error message along the lines of "An internal error occured, missing data" (again, dont remember exact). I really do not know what to do anymore.

Did a PRAM reset a few times, it seems like the reset worked, although booting was still dead.

Then I tried an SMC reset, and that just killed everything. Read below to see what it did.

Now i was trying again, and this time NOTHING works. Whenever i try ANY combination of startup commands, it chimes, and shows a black screen. Now this is the point where I am furious because before I could have formatted, alas losing my data, but gaining my computer, but now, I can't even get my computer back! One thing that might be important to mention as well is that while doing all these recovery procedures, the mac got almost unbearably hot, and the fans wouldnt do anything, meaning I could only do so much before I had to turn it off and wait for it to get cooler. Now I do know that the hard drive is not physically dead (not 100%) because I ran a SMART check on it around 3 weeks ago and it passed normally, everything fully fine, no worries anywhere. This mac has also never been dropped, and has been treated with EXTREMELY good care (no damage at all, always in a case, always in its sleeve, transported like its a holy item from the heavens).

If anyone could help I would be VERY happy, and would love to offer a bounty, but my account here can't do that since it's new.

Comment: 10.11.3 was released last week. 10.11.4 has not been released yet. Did you mean 10.11.3, or did you somehow get your hands on a beta of 10.11.4?

Comment: @Spiff Yeh it's beta. I've been on beta forever now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've had a hardware failure at this point. Time to have an Apple authorized Mac service technician take a look at it. Random hardware failures can happen even to well-cared-for machines. It's not likely that the 10.11.x update caused this. It's probably just a coincidence.

There's a good possibility that it's your MLB (Main Logic Board, a.k.a. "motherboard") that failed, not your SSD. So your data may still be intact. If you don't have good backups (shame on you), be very explicit with your technician that you want to try to keep the data on the SSD.

Comment: Most of the stuff is backed up. There are a few things that weren't backed up though, and those are very important. (music production logic files). Also, i dont think its the logic board because it did boot into Internet Recovery twice (still a bit weird) but it did. This same thing happened to my external backup drive over winter break. My partition tables broke on it, and gave me a hard day recovering the files (I got most of the things back). Problem is this is much harder on a boot drive.